# Saving nested data via angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to save the contents of a form into a hierarchical data structure:

```
$scope.milestones = [
    {milestoneName: "milestone 1",
    id:"milestoneOne",
    headingID:"headingOne",
    panelClass:"in",
    tasks:[
        {
        taskSubject:"Get cost agreement confirmation",
        category:"#7FFF00",
        dueDate:"July 5, 2015",
        repeat: true,
        assignee:"Jiman Ilitad",
        estHours:"3"},
        {
        taskSubject:"Get cost agreement confirmation",
        category:"#7FFF00",
        dueDate:"July 5, 2015",
        repeat: true,
        assignee:"Jiman Ilitad",
        estHours:"3"}
    ]}
];
```

I'm using ng-repeat to display milestones and then within each of the milestones I have tasks. Each milestone can have one or more tasks added to it via a basic html form where each input corresponds with a value in the push.

Here is the script which defines the push:

```
$scope.addTask = function(index){
    $scope.milestones.tasks.push({
        taskSubject: $scope.index.formTaskSubject,
        category: $scope.index.formCategory,
        dueDate: $scope.index.formDate,
        repeat: $scope.index.formRepeat,
        assignee: $scope.index.formAssignee,
        estHours: $scope.index.formEstTime
        })
    };
```

I'm currently getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you're trying to call the method `push` on something that doesn't exist. Since `$scope.milestones` is an array, you need to specify which element in that array you're trying to add a task to.

Based on your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YmlBuu?p=preview), you just need to call `addTask()` with an additional parameter specifying the index of the milestone you wish to modify.

In your `ng-click`, pass in an index to the milestone. For example, change:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTask()">Save</a>
```

To:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTask($index)">Save</a>
```

The above assumes that `$index` is the index to your `$scope.milestones` array, which is assigned by `ng-repeat="milestone in milestones"`. It can easily change if you nest `ng-repeat`s, breaking your code.

To avoid this, just pass the `milestone` object itself directly into `addTask`.

In your HTML:

```
<div ... ng-repeat="milestone in milestones" ...>
  ...
  <a ... ng-click="addTaskTo(milestone)" ...>Save</a>
  ...
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.addTaskTo = function(milestone) {
  milestone.tasks.push(...);
```

Comment: I decided to create a plunk to make it a little easier to communicate. I made this change and now get the same error for tasks. http://plnkr.co/edit/YmlBuu?p=preview 

*clicking save within "milestone 1" under the "add task" button will produce the error*

Comment: Thanks @featherz, the plunker helps. Notice that in your `ng-click="addTask()"` you're not passing in any parameters, yet `function addTask(milestoneIndex) { ... }` expects a parameter. `addTask($index)` is the value for `ng-click` you need, but the way the page is structured makes it easy for this to break (not enough room in comments to explain why). Consider passing in the `milestone` object itself instead of an index to an array.

Comment: I thought I had this all figured out but can't seem to get it to post form data contents back to the page. It posts empty data even when the form is filled in. Any ideas? http://plnkr.co/edit/3dEnBkYS502DxnAPFefg?p=preview

Comment: It has to do with scopes & in which scope your form fields are defined. `$scope` refers to your controller's scope, but `ng-repeat="milestone in milestones"` creates a new scope for each `milestone`. So, `$scope.formDate` doesn't exist because there are multiple `formDate`s, one for each `milestone`. You need to pass in each of those values form values into `addTask` (http://plnkr.co/edit/PAij6n1YBr0z2IuqeYf9?p=preview). Or if you're brave, you can try creating a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for your milestone panel :)